# windows shell : extract command from files and run them

Tags: batch-file

How to extract a set of commands from a `bat` file respecting certain pattern and run them in bach?

example :
file.txt

```
export TOOLCHAIN="multi"
# Version of toolchain (optional)
# Location of toolchain (optional for WINDOWS)
export TOOLPATH="D:/Tools/compiler/GHS/GHS_COMPILER/PPC"
```

in this example, I'm looking for a command which could

1. find all the lines starting with `export`
2. extract the command
3. run the command

output:

```
set TOOLCHAIN="multi"
set TOOLPATH="D:/Tools/compiler/GHS/GHS_COMPILER/PPC"
```

Comment: Simple: `for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('findstr "^export" file.txt') do set %%b`  BTW your description is confusing; you want not to _"run the command"_, but to "set a variable with the command"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type file.txt ^|findstr /B "export"') do (
  set "output=%%i"
  set myCMD=!output:export=set!
  echo !myCMD!
 )
```

Simply loop through type command of `file.txt` then `findstr` the word export in the beginning of the line, and replace with set.

This will simply `echo` the full command, you can remove `echo` when happy with the results to actually run set command.